# How to modify this rsync command to find out the directory with '.' in Python?

Tags: python, rsync, python-2.6

I am using rsync command with python like this:

```
rsync_out = subprocess.Popen(['sshpass', '-p', password, 'rsync', '--recursive', source], 
                     stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
        command = subprocess.Popen(('grep', '\.'), stdin=rsync_out.stdout, stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0]
```

The purpose of using grep to display files like this:

```
rathi/20090209.02s1.2_sequence.txt

rathi/20090729.02s4.2_sequence.txt.gz

rathi/Homo_sapiens_UCSC_hg19.tar.gz

    rathi/hello/ok.txt
```

instead of

```
rathi

rathi/20090209.02s1.2_sequence.txt

rathi/20090729.02s4.2_sequence.txt.gz

rathi/Homo_sapiens_UCSC_hg19.tar.gz

hello

rathi/hello/ok.txt
```

It's works fine except if the directory name has `'.'` on it.

If there's a directory names hello.v1 then the output would be:

```
rathi/hello.v1
rathi/hello.v1/ok.txt
```

Since hello.v1 is a directory name I only want to show like this:

```
rathi/hello.v1/ok.txt
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally I wouldn't bother using `grep`, I'd simply use Python's own string filtering - however, that wasn't the question you asked.

Since the filenames are remote and Python sees them as simply strings then we can't use any of Python's own file manipulation routines (e.g. `os.path.isdir()`). So, I think you have three basic approaches:

1. Split each string by slashes and use this to build your own representation of the filesystem tree in memory. Then, do a pass through the tree and only display leaf nodes (i.e. files).
2. If you can assume that files within a directory are always listed immediately after that directory, then you can do a quick check against the previous entries to see if this entry is a file within one of those directories.
3. Use meta-information from `rsync`.

I would suggest the third option. My experience with `rsync` is that it usually gives you full file information like this:

```
drwxr-xr-x        4096 2013/06/14 17:19:13 tmp/t
-rwxrwxr-x       14532 2013/06/14 17:17:23 tmp/t/a.out
-rwxrwxr-x       14539 2013/06/14 17:19:13 tmp/t/static-order
```

In your example I can't see any code which removes this additional information, and you could easily use this to filter out directories by looking for any line which starts with a `d` instead of a `-`.

If you don't have this extended information, you'll need to do one of the other two. The first option is pretty simple - just split by slashes and then descend a standard tree structure, adding entries for directories and files which haven't been seen yet. Once all the entries have been parsed, you can traverse the tree and print out anything which is a node with no children.

The second option is something more complicated, but more memory efficient, where you maintain a list of parent directories and check whether they're a prefix of the current item in the list. If so, you can be sure the previous one is a directory and the current one is a file, so you can mark the previous one as something not to show. You can also throw items off this list once you've recursed "out" of that directory, provided that `rsync` returns them in a predictable order. You have to make sure you only check for prefixes at slash boundaries (so `foo/dir` is not a parent of `foo/dir-bar`, but it is a parent of `foo/dir/bar`). Generally this approach is rather fiddly, and unless you're dealing with an awfully large directory tree then one of the other approaches is probably preferable.

By the way, either of the pure string-based approaches also have the disadvantage that an empty directory will be indistinguishable from a file, since it's only the presence or absence of files within a directory which distinguishes them. This is another reason I suggest using the meta-information from `rsync`.

**EDIT**

As requested, an example using the `rsync` meta-data:

```
import subprocess

cmdline = ["rsync", "-e", "ssh", "-r", "user@host:/dir"]
proc = subprocess.Popen(cmdline, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
for entry in proc.stdout:
    items = entry.strip().split(None, 4)
    if not items[0].startswith("d") and "." in items[4]:
        print items[4]
```

In this example, I'm invoking `rsync` directly and having it use `ssh`, assuming that appropriate SSH keys are set up. I would strongly suggest using SSH keys instead of the `sshpass` utility - storing your passwords in plaintext is a really bad idea from a security perspective. You can always set up your keys with no passphrase if you're not worried about them being stolen. There are lots of pages which explain how to create SSH keys ([this one](http://www.debian.org/devel/passwordlessssh), for example).

Replace `user`, `host` and `/dir` with your username on the remote machine, the hostname of the remote machine and the parent directory you wish to list on the remote machine (you can omit `/dir` if you want to list the user's home directory). Otherwise the code should run unmodified. If will print the path name of each file that it founds, skipping directories and items which don't contain a dot. If your dot filter was just an attempt to skip directories as well, you can omit 'and "." in items[4]'.

**EDIT 2**

This example just prints the entries, but of course you'll presumably want to do something else. If you want to be really clever, you could write it as a generator which calls `yield` on the items as they crop up. I've got an example of this below, which also prints the items but you can see how it can be used to do anything else. I've also added some better error handling to make sure the use of `subprocess` can't deadlock:

**EDIT 3:** *I've updated this example to also include file size and modification time. This is based on what I get back from my `rsync` - if yours has a different format you might need to use different members from `items` or possible change the format string to `strptime()` to match the formats returned by your `rsync`.*

```
from datetime import datetime
import os
import subprocess

def find_remote_files(hostspec):
    cmdline = ["rsync", "-e", "ssh", "-r", hostspec]
    with open(os.devnull, "w") as devnull:
        proc = subprocess.Popen(cmdline, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=devnull)
        try:
            for entry in proc.stdout:
                items = entry.strip().split(None, 4)
                if not items[0].startswith("d"):
                    dt = datetime.strptime(" ".join(items[2:4]),
                                           "%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S")
                    yield (int(items[1]), dt, items[4])
            proc.wait()
        except:
            # On any exception, terminate process and re-raise exception.
            proc.terminate()
            proc.wait()
            raise

for filesize, filedate, filename in find_remote_files("user@host:/dir"):
    print "Filename: %s" % (filename,)
    print "(%d bytes, modified %s)" % (filesize, filedate.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"))
```

You should be able to paste the whole `find_remote_files()` function into your code and use it directly, if you like.

Comment: Thanks for the wonderful answer. I prefer the third approach. Can you give example on my case. Thanks

Comment: I've added a couple of examples to my post, which hopefully answers your question. I would suggest using the generator function from the second one, hopefully the example makes clear how to use it. This one is a little more complicated than the first, but it handles some rare termination cases which could cause deadlocks in the first example if `rsync` suffers an error.

Comment: Thanks for the wonderful answer but I want to get the size and the date the file was created too.

Comment: I have made a different function to get date and size. For example items[1] gives the date. It is possible to yield all three with the same function and call function like:
a, b, c = [i for i in find_remote_files('hostname')]

Comment: On my system, `items[1]` is the file size, `items[2]` is the date and `items[3]` is the time - are you sure `items[1]` is the date on yours? Anyway, you should be able to parse the items pretty easily. I've updated the second example above to show how you might go about it. As you can see, if you yield a `tuple` of 3 items, you can assign to the same number of items in the `for` loop, which is really convenient.